# javascript/jquery lets my page load halfway

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, scroll

I've got his strange bug where my page scrolls to the middle somewhere when i load the page. the site can be checked here.  http://wilpegroup.webshoptool.nl/

I dont have a clue what is wrong but i guess its somewhere in this script below because that the scroll script.

```
$(function() {
  $('a[href*=#]:not([href=#])').click(function() {
    if (location.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') == this.pathname.replace(/^\//,'') && location.hostname == this.hostname) {
      var target = $(this.hash);
      target = target.length ? target : $('[name=' + this.hash.slice(1) +']');
      if (target.length) {
        $('html,body').animate({
          scrollTop: target.offset().top
        }, 1000);
        return false;
      }
    }
  });
});
```

I hope this is enough information if you guys need any more tell me.

Comment: That code triggers only on click so it can't be the cause.

Comment: The script.js is not included properly in your html file.

Comment: @Juhana true but its the only script thats has something to do with scrolling so i was thinking i might did something wrong.

Comment: @AmitJS94       <script type="text/javascript" src"js/script.js"></script> its not wrong right? or what do you mean?

Comment: @Juhana, can't be it... was my gut-reaction. But then I put a breakpoint in it and it turns out, it is running?!?

Comment: @marijn try not using the convenience method (.click can be either .on or .trigger, based on some internal magic) and use `.on('click', function()`. No guarantee, just trying to eliminate causes.

Comment: @Windgazer i just did the same and it look like it is running for some reason.... really strange wasn't able figure out why yet

Comment: If you see the source view-source:http://wilpegroup.webshoptool.nl/  and search for script.js you can't open it and it is not getting loaded ( you can check the network panel ). Could you fix that ? then I can debug the js file.

Comment: I just edited the file like you said but its not working, i uploaded it on the webserver again so you can take a look maybe i didn't understand it right.

Comment: @AmitJS94 that script is not used on this page its only used for parallax on another page

Comment: @marijn I'm 95% sure it's timelinr that's performing a 'click' on it's first element to highlight it, which in turn triggers your 'onclick' method, which then scrolls your timeline into view

Comment: @Windgazer i just replaced .on with .trigger now its not scrolling to the middle anymore but is the animation not working anymore. Ill check the timeline now want me to share the code or can you see it already?

Comment: One last desperate attempt: `$().timelinr({
            arrowKeys: 'true', startAt: 0
          })`

Comment: @Windgazer i just tried it and its not working. I dont get it anymore what can be a salution

Comment: Sorry Marijn, I have only so much time to try and help people out :( Timelinr will always, unless you patch it somehow, click on an element in your timeline, this will cause the page to 'scroll'. Your scroll script just makes it scroll smoothly. I had hoped that telling it to 'startAt: 0' it would not select any element, instead it just goes for the end of your timeline instead.